# How to disable a JXTaskPane

Tags: java, swingx

So I have 3 collapsable JXTaskPanes and what I want to do is only show one task pane at a time i.e. if a user clicks task pane #1, #2 and #3 are collapsed and #1 is expanded etc.

I cant add an actionlistener to the JXTaskPanes as it does not exist. 
I tried mouse listeners but it's quite buggy (doesn't always work: sometimes it wont one of the 2)

Basically, I need a way to, for example, collapse task panes #2 and #3 when #1 is expanded.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if the `JXTaskPane` fires any property changed events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having been curious about this question, I did a little more Googling and stumbled across [this](http://layerxml.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/auto-collapsing-jxtaskpane/) blog which might be of interest

Comment: +1 good dig :-) @Omar sounds reasonable - you might consider to file a feature request in the SwingX issue tracker. Should be easy enough to implement, so there's a good chance it might happen for 1.6.5 :-)

Comment: Solved in the link posted by @MadProgrammer Thanks!
you just need to add a ChangeListener for the collapse event